# Xpath get node that only contains nodes of a certain type

Tags: xpath

Take this (`id` attributes only added so I can refer to them below)

```
<div id="one">
   <figure>foo</figure>
   <figure>bar</figure>
</div>
<div id="two">
   <figure>foo</figure>
   <div>bar</div>
</div>
<div id="three">
   <div>bar</div>
</div>
```

How can I select all `div` elements whose children are *all* `figure` elements, i.e. selecting div one only in the given example?

I sort of need `//div[count(not figure)>0]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible way :

```
//div[not(*[name() != 'figure']) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]
```

The left-side of `and` make sure the `div` doesn't have child element named other than 'figure', and the right-side make sure it doesn't have non-empty child text node.

or, the same approach but using `count()` :

```
//div[count(*[name() != 'figure']|text()[normalize-space()]) = 0]
```

Comment: Thanks, the text stuff is something I'd not thought of. What do you think of my answer? Seems to work, but I bow to your 56.6k experience!

Comment: Haha.. you don't need to. Yes, your answer should also work. The catch probably when you have a `div` that contains a mix of `<figure>` and text node, like `<div id="four">
   <figure>foo</figure>
   bar
</div>` (I assume this `div` doesn't qualify for selection)

Comment: Yeah, I expect to ignore empty (spaces) text nodes and I don't need to worry about non-empty text nodes so I'm counting `*`, not `node()`. i.e. *element* nodes only. This ignores text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
//div[figure][count(figure) = count(*)]
```

This finds divs that must contain at least one `figure`, and then it checks that the count of `figure` elements matches the count of all other elements; if this is true then it cannot contain anything else.